# Get the location of followers in Instagram

Tags: api, instagram-api

I noticed that a service called Iconosquare (and even some others) provides the location of the followers for the their platform users. 
I am interested in using the Instagram API in order to get the location/age/gender (audience data) of my users' followers.

I read ALL the [Instagram API documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) but there is no endpoint that can provide this kind of data.

PS : I heard about the Instagram Insight API but it's not released yet (2016/2/7).

How can they do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to imagine a solution :

For a specific user/token :

- Get the list of followers with a public profile

Then for each follower :

- Get the location of the last 10 or 20 (or even 100) posts
- Create an average of latitude/longitude of that located posts
- Assume that the followers come from this point (then get the name of the nearest city or country)

It's based on one major presumption about the location of the post of followers. (I imagine that i will exclude some points that are too far from the average because it might be travel posts)

I would be happy to get a feedback about doing it this way.

Thanks,